# Index or HLookup working "alone" but not working inside ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, vlookup, array-formulas

I'm  trying to put the following formulas inside an ArrayFormula but the result is wrong (keep providing the first row result):

**Working in each single cell**

```
=INDEX($D$2:$AKA;match($A2:A;$A$2:A;false);MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(TODAY());1);$D$1:$AKA$1;false))
```

**Showing the same result in all cells**

```
=arrayformula(IF(LEN($A$2:A);INDEX($D$2:$AKA;match($A2:A;$A$2:A;false);MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY());MONTH(TODAY());1);$D$1:$AKA$1;false));))
```

[image: Expected/Results]

[Gsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-mHbulrDEGFyTssoMCQfmhdpcEmbwwnnzQffoavx0tM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(EOMONTH(TODAY(); -1)+1; D1:1000; IF(A2:A="";;ROW(A2:A)); 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also try `QUERY()` approach.

```
=QUERY(INDEX(D2:5000;;MATCH(EOMONTH(TODAY();-1)+1;D1:1));"limit " & COUNTA(A2:A))
```

[image]